# Code Running extremely slow due to while() in processing

Tags: java, processing, 2d-games

I am programming a snake clone in processing and everything was going well until I inserted a while() function, now the game isn't running at the 5 fps that it is supposed to. I've tried everything and can't seem to solve the problem, does anybody know what's going on?

```
int playerX = 400;
int playerY = 400;
void setup(){
  size(1350,655);
  frameRate(5);
    noStroke();

};

int[] posX = {playerX,playerX-17};


int[] posY = {playerY,playerY};

void draw(){
  background(0,0,0);

  if (keyCode == UP) {  playerY -= 17;};
  if (keyCode == DOWN) {  playerY += 17;};
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {  playerX -= 17;};
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {  playerX += 17;};

  int i = posX.length;
  while(i>0){
  posX[1] = posX[0];
  posY[1] = posY[0];
  i++;};


  posX[0] =playerX;
  posY[0] =playerY;

snakeBlock(posX[0],posY[0]);

snakeBlock(posX[1],posY[1]);
};

void  snakeBlock(int snakeX,int snakeY){
  fill(255,2550);
  rect(snakeX,snakeY,15,15);
};
```

Comment: use `i--` in your while, however still it does not make much sense. What is this `while` expected to do?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this loop:

```
while(i > 0){
  posX[1] = posX[0];
  posY[1] = posY[0];
  i++;
}
```

This loop keeps going as long as `i` is greater than `0`. But inside the loop, `i` only increases. When will it ever become less than `0`? It won't! So this loop will never exit.

To be more accurate, it will only exit when the number becomes so large that it **overflows** and starts back over at the minimum value.

Also note that since you aren't even using the `i` variable inside this loop, you don't really need the loop at all.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I can't believe I didn't notice, it was so obvious!

Comment: @GriffinBrown No problem. Btw you should really get into the habit of [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code, that way you can catch errors like this.

Comment: Well, it will exit eventually when `i` overflows. Else the program wouldn't run at all instead of veeery slowly.